# HTML tag attribute referenced to an object

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object that acts like a cursor(table) and it's like this:

```
function cursor() {
  this.code = "";
  this.name = ""; }
```

Then I have a variable that will be used as the cursor itself:

```
var lib_book = new cursor();
```

Then I have a table with a custom attribute 'record_source' which is referenced to my cursor:

```
<table record_source="lib_book" id="grdbook">
```

Now I have a Refresh_Record function that binds the cursor to the table object. I can do it with this code: (sorry for not including all the codes)

```
Refresh_Record(lib_book,grdbook);
```

Now the question is this, is there a way to change the code to this:

```
Refresh_Record(grdbook);
```

since I have lib_book as an attribute. But lib_book is just a string there. Is there a way that I can reference the record_source attribute to the actual cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Save all your cursors in a global array, and save array index of cursor as attribute in table.

you can do it other way by using eval,but using eval is not a good idea